# Can't return an array from method in main

Tags: java, arrays, k-means

I'm very beginner in Java. This is my univercity work of creating a KMeans algorithm. A person writes digits in `SAMPLES` and number of centers in `NUM_CLUSTERS`. Algorithm gives cluster center `Points`

I need to return an array from this method but I can't:

`public static int[][] getCentroid_arr(int SAMPLES[],int NUM_CLUSTERS,int centroid_arr[][])`.

What exactly array? - It's shown in Console:

```
Points
1, 2, 7, 22, 44,
```

It's necessary to return an array because I want to use it for checking in JUnit test.
Instead of `return centroid_arr` must be this one sorted array:
 `printArray(arr_sort_asc(sorted_distTocentroid_arr))`

After spending about 3 days with this issue I still have no idea how to resolve a problem. I can only get it in print.

I'd be thankfull for any help.

```
    package kmeans;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class KM_don_touch {

    private static final int NUM_CLUSTERS = 5;    // Total clusters.

    private static final int SAMPLES[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 22, 44, 50};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("data size is: " + SAMPLES.length);
        System.out.println("number of clusters is: " + NUM_CLUSTERS);
        System.out.print("dataset is: ");
        printArray(SAMPLES);
        System.out.println();

        int maxDiffData_arr[]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS];        

        Kmeans_test3 get_prepare_data = new Kmeans_test3();
        maxDiffData_arr=get_prepare_data.prepare_data(SAMPLES);

        int centroid_arr[][]=new int[2][NUM_CLUSTERS];
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
            centroid_arr[0][i] = 0;
            centroid_arr[1][i] = SAMPLES[maxDiffData_arr[i]];
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("centroid_arr 0 is: ");
        printArray(centroid_arr[0]);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("centroid_arr 1 is: ");
        printArray(centroid_arr[1]);

        System.out.println();

        getCentroid_arr(SAMPLES, NUM_CLUSTERS, centroid_arr);       
    }   

    public static void firstDiffSort(int[] difference){
        int tmp[]=new int[difference.length];
        tmp = arr_sort_desc(difference);
        for (int i=0; i<difference.length; i++){
        }
    }

    public static int[] arr_sort_desc(int[] arr) {
        int tmp;    
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[k] < arr[j]) { 
                tmp = arr[k];       
                arr[k] = arr[j];        
                arr[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        } 
        return arr;
    }

    public static int[] arr_sort_asc(int[] arr) {
        int tmp;    
        for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[k] > arr[j]) { 
                tmp = arr[k];       
                arr[k] = arr[j];        
                arr[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        } 
        return arr;
    }

    public static int getMinValue(int[] numbers){
          int minValue = numbers[0];
          for(int i=1; i<numbers.length; i++){
            if(numbers[i] < minValue){
                minValue = numbers[i];
            }
          }
          return minValue;
    }

    public static int FindSmallest (int [] arr1){
           int index = 0;
           int min = arr1[index];
           for (int i=1; i<arr1.length; i++){
               if (arr1[i] < min ){
                   min = arr1[i];
                   index = i;
               }
           }
           return index;
    }

    public static int[][] getCentroid_arr(int SAMPLES[],int NUM_CLUSTERS,int centroid_arr[][]){
            int distance[][]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS][SAMPLES.length];
            int cluster[]=new int[SAMPLES.length];
            int clusternodecount[]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS];
            int storedData[][]=new int[1][NUM_CLUSTERS];
            int clusterelements[][]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS][SAMPLES.length];          

            centroid_arr[0] = centroid_arr[1];
            centroid_arr[1]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS];
            for (int i=0; i<NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
                centroid_arr[1][i] = 0;
            }               

            System.out.println("========== Starting to get new centroid_arr =========");

            //сложность алгоритма С2
            for(int i=0;i<NUM_CLUSTERS;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<SAMPLES.length;j++){
                    distance[i][j]=Math.abs(SAMPLES[j]-centroid_arr[0][i]);
                    System.out.print(distance[i][j]+" ,");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }           

            System.out.println("========== Just ranspose =========");
            int smallerDistance=0;
            int[][] numbers = new int[SAMPLES.length][NUM_CLUSTERS];

            for(int i=0;i<SAMPLES.length;i++){
                for(int j=0; j<NUM_CLUSTERS; j++){
                    numbers[i][j]=distance[j][i];
                    System.out.print(numbers[i][j]+", ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                smallerDistance = FindSmallest(numbers[i]);
                centroid_arr[1][smallerDistance] = centroid_arr[1][smallerDistance]+SAMPLES[i];
                clusternodecount[smallerDistance]=clusternodecount[smallerDistance]+1;
                cluster[i]=smallerDistance;             
            }

            System.out.println("New clusters are ");

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
                System.out.print("C" + (i + 1) + ": ");
                for (int j = 0; j < SAMPLES.length; j++) {
                    if (cluster[j] == i)
                        System.out.print(SAMPLES[j] + ", ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("======================================== ");

            System.out.println("New centroid_arr is ");

            for (int k = 0; k < NUM_CLUSTERS; k++) {
                centroid_arr[1][k] = centroid_arr[1][k] / clusternodecount[k];
                System.out.print(centroid_arr[1][k] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            boolean isAchived = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_CLUSTERS; j++) {
                if (isAchived && centroid_arr[0][j] == centroid_arr[1][j]) {
                    isAchived = true;
                    continue;
                }
                isAchived = false;
            }

            if (!isAchived) {
                getCentroid_arr(SAMPLES, NUM_CLUSTERS, centroid_arr);
            }

            if (isAchived) {
                System.out.println("======================================== ");
                System.out.println(" Final Cluster is ");
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLUSTERS; i++) {
                    System.out.print("C" + (i + 1) + ": ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < SAMPLES.length; j++) {
                        if (cluster[j] == i)
                            System.out.print(SAMPLES[j] + ", ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            for (int i=0; i<SAMPLES.length; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<NUM_CLUSTERS; j++){
                    if (j==cluster[i])
                        clusterelements[j][i]=SAMPLES[i];   
                }
            }

            int distTocentroid_arr[][]=new int[NUM_CLUSTERS][SAMPLES.length];   
            for (int i=0; i<NUM_CLUSTERS; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<SAMPLES.length; j++){
                    distTocentroid_arr[i][j]=Math.abs(centroid_arr[1][i]-clusterelements[i][j]);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Points:");
            int sorted_distTocentroid_arr[] = new int[NUM_CLUSTERS];
            for (int i=0; i<NUM_CLUSTERS; i++){ 
                smallerDistance = FindSmallest(distTocentroid_arr[i]);
                sorted_distTocentroid_arr[i]=clusterelements[i][smallerDistance];
            }

            printArray(arr_sort_asc(sorted_distTocentroid_arr));        
            }
            return centroid_arr;
    }   

    public int[] prepare_data(int[] arr) {
        int sorted_arr[] = arr_sort_desc(SAMPLES);
        int maxDiff_arr[] = new int[SAMPLES.length];
        int sorted_diff[] = new int[SAMPLES.length];

        maxDiff_arr[0] = Math.abs(sorted_arr[0] - sorted_arr[1]);
        for (int i = 1; i < SAMPLES.length; i++) {
            maxDiff_arr[i] = Math.abs(sorted_arr[i] - sorted_arr[i - 1]);
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> m1= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int k=0;
        for(int i:maxDiff_arr){
            m1.put(k++, i);
        }
        m1= sortByValues(m1);

        int i=0;
        for (int key: m1.keySet()){
             sorted_diff[i++]=key;
        }
        return sorted_diff;

    }

    public static <K extends Comparable,V extends Comparable> Map<K,V> sortByValues(Map<K,V> map){
        List<Map.Entry<K,V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K,V>>(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<K, V> o1, Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
            }
        });
        Map<K,V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
        for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: entries){
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
        }
    }

    public static void printArray2(int[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[1][i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymi2Z.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I can't return array from the method"? Is there an error? does it not compile? Also, preferrably you should trim the amount of code in question, leaving [mcve]. I would expect that most of what's in that code snippet is not strictly related to your problem.

Comment: I reduced amount of code.If i pass sorted_distTocentroid_arr instead of centroid_arr it throws an error: sorted_distTocentroid_arr can not be resolved to a variable

Comment: Still not clear what's not working though. And now your new code missing `centroid_arr` in `main`, so example won't compile.

Comment: I added the full code in a link above the code. Have no idea how to reduce it otherwise. Without full code it will not work.

Comment: Add error message

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
`        Kmeans_test3 get_prepare_data = new Kmeans_test3();?` (Kmeans_test3). What's the purpose of the for-loop, doing nothing in `firstDiffSort`?

Comment: "Can't return an array from method in main" - main in Java is supposed to return void - or is this an unclear description.